# DocuSign API Error: A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. AllowRequireSignerCertificate

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting an error when trying to use CreateEnvelopeFromTemplate from the SOAP API.  The error states:

**"A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. Plan item: AllowRequireSignerCertificate"**

It is worth noting that I have a demo account only, and not a production account.  Other useful info:

- SOAP API
- .NET MVC 4.5 Application
- C#

Code Snippet:

```
DS.TemplateReference templateReference = new DS.DocuSignAPI.TemplateReference();
templateReference.Template = _templateID;
templateReference.TemplateLocation = DS.TemplateLocationCode.Server;

DS.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DS.EnvelopeInformation();
envelopeInfo.AccountId = _accountId;
envelopeInfo.Subject = "Test Subject";
envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "Test Email Content";

DS.EnvelopeStatus status = client.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(new DS.TemplateReference[ {templateReference}, _recipients, envelopeInfo, false); -- fails here
```

Comment: Hmm, I know there have been some issues with our demo server recently, not sure if they are resolved yet.  However I know I've also seen that error before when there are backwards compatibility issues with templates.  As a test, can you please try creating a new template real quick and reference that in your code to see if the error goes away?

Comment: This template was just created yesterday, so it is brand new.  However, I will try and see what happens.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: As suspected, the same error occurs on the new template created.  Does it matter in what form the template originated?  This was started as a Word Doc (.doc extension).

Comment: I'm following up on my side about this, I believe there's an issue with creating envelopes from templates on demo server right now.  I'll post something here once I know more.  Sending signature requests on document are working, just not from a template at the moment, and this is only on the demo server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with DocuSign's demo.docusign.net server.  I believe the fix is going in today but might not get pushed to demo until tomorrow.  Please check back on this tomorrow.

Comment: It is working now.  Thanks.  I have a new question, but I'll post in another thread.